# Convert SQL update query to c# LINQ code

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, xml-column

I want to convert this SQL query to C# code:

```
UPDATE Layouts 
SET LayoutDetails.modify('delete /ColumnLayout/LayoutColumns/Column[@PropertyId = sql:variable("@propId")]') 
WHERE LayoutId = 236
```

This query deletes a node in a XML column in a SQL Server table. I want to perform a similar operation in C# using LINQ.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post some code.

Comment: Which ORM you're using? I think the `UPDATE` statement is ORM-based, LINQ to SQL/LINQ to Entities mainly used for `SELECT` statements.

Comment: @IpsitGaur : Usually for updating any record , will get the relevant record with the layoutid , modify relevant data field and savechanges. But here i have to play with XML column so absolutely no idea . If nothing works, i have to go with ADO.net

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  EntityFramework

Comment: @Prasu Just perform a simple SELECT query first, e.g. (`db.Layouts.Where(x => x.ColumnName == value`), assign all updated values to the result set and use `db.SaveChanges()` method (`db` is your `DbSet` name).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  Yeah that is how we usually update a record using EF, but here i want to delete a node which contains propertyid as 43. Whole node ned to be removed from XML column data.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ does not have anything like this available, because LINQ doesn't interact with a database in that way. I'm not sure what you are using to connect to your database, but there should be something in there that would allow you to do this.

As an example, Entity Framework has SaveChanges(), which will push any changes made to objects as an UPDATE sql command to the database you're connected to. Other types of ORMs should have something similar.

Comment: Yeah i know about Savechanges method in entityframework, but i wanted to know about updating an XML column in LINQ query and savechanges to DB.

Comment: @Prasu There's something missing here, then - you will need something other than LINQ to do this. LINQ will let you manipulate collections, but it doesn't have anything to do with pushing changes to anything.

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to read that XML column, then you can update that column and then use `SaveChanges()` method. like

```
var details = (from lay in context.Layouts where lay.id = 236 select lay).firstOrdefalut();

details.ColumnLayout.LayoutColumns.PropertyId = yourId;

saveChange();
```

Check it will be helpful

Comment: Yeah that is how we usually update a record using EF, but here i want to delete a node which contains propertyid as 43. Whole node ned to be removed from XML column data.